# Mechanism to control spring release

Tags: mechanisms, project-management

okay so I’m trying to build a tennis ball launcher for my school so we can showcase it- my teacher helped me get motors and stuff setup similar to this image.

Question: How would I include a spring so that (after we manually compress it) anyone can use a button or something to release the spring and push the ball towards the wheels please? I can’t find anything simple? ![enter image description here]![enter image description here][image]

I was thinking of having a bung or something at the end of the spring??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea just for the sake of fun.

[image]

Suggested locking mechanism.

[image]

Crossectional View

[image]

Comment: How do we control the piston please for it to release? Can I remote sort of control it?

Comment: You need to manually load the ball and slide the front plate against the piston or spring to set the ball into ready to shot position, then release the handle to propel the ball. You can make a vertical notch near the end of the slot to lock the handle if desired.

Comment: Is there a way to use a motor to release it from the notch please then the motor turns off after that?

Comment: I think it can but requires adding much more details. The simple idea is to attach something to the handlers after it has been set in the ready position, then start the motor to lift the handler to the shoot position. However, the trick is this lock needs to be either released upon impact or follow the motion of the handlers. I'll leave it to you to think about.

Comment: Hi, what’s a handler please? My teacher said that the piston idea is in budget if we use a Bung instead as we have lots of those in Science department downstairs

Comment: Please see the added crossectional view.

Comment: Thank you, that’s a cool diagram

Comment: Now we agreed on the basic mechanics, however, I am afraid it wouldn't achieve the goal as a tennis ball launcher. In order for the ball to fly high and far, we need to add an impulsive force (impact) when the plate/piston strikes the ball hard, as in the striking of a golf ball rather than pushing the ball. A distance needs to be created between the striking face and the ball to get the required momentum. I'll let you think about it, see how to modify the design. Discuss with your instructor, then let me know if you run into a hard time coming up with a modification.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a spring?

Have a vertical tube with a gentle curve to feed the balls and all you need is a small pin to stop the balls getting to the drive mechanism. The mass of the balls will autofeed...

Or you can make a "gate" to allow one at a time... Perhaps think of a pinball machine.

So, how about two pins which need to be linked together. As one moves out to allow the ball to get to the drive wheels, the other moves in to prevent "full auto"...

[image]

Comment: Hi, my teacher said for safety (so we can stand away) and so that people can press it and watch the ball shoot off, so to make it interactive and more fun? Some kids may use it too I think

Comment: Yeah, I just need a way to make the spring release button controlled? The pinball one we would hold I think and release manually?

Comment: Will you use your rapid fire ability device for good? Or for evil? A simple mechanical button will require you to be up close so that fails if safety is your concern. Propose the gravity feed tube to your teacher. It is also safer in the sense you don't need to be at the business end to load. No accidental ball in the face if you load it while it is on.

Comment: Hi, Sir said that he wanted like a controller with just one switch sort of thing to release the spring, he said we have wire to make it like at least 3m long

Comment: It's still easier to do that with the gravity fed tube. You just use a solenoid for the pin. All you need is tube, solenoid, and a hole. With spring loading you need to add platforms, slots, springs, and latches. You do not need to blindly follow teacher instructions. You can propose better, simpler, safer methods. Did you know real tennis ball launchers are gravity fed? Your image is cropped from a gravity feed image. What is the problem?

Comment: @Edwin see edit.

Comment: Hi thanks Mike! That’s a cool idea, I’ll ask sir before I leave today. Finish in 18mins

Comment: Hi, okay I asked Sir and he said pin thing seems a little ‘shoddy’, I suggested to add like a motor to the pin for a switch can pull it out but he still wants that controlled release spring…

Comment: Is there not like a way to release the spring with like an on off switch please? We have lots of them at my school. So maybe after we compress the spring, a button releases it?

Comment: So use two solenoids for the pins and one push button controls both...

Comment: @Edwin That's unfortunate. I have no idea why your teacher wants a muzzle loader when people have been trying to get away from muzzle loaders to breechloaders for centuries. The advantage of a muzzleloaders is that it was simpler but in this case it is more complicated.

Comment: How would the solenoids move please from a push button? Sorry I don’t get that bit please? And are solenoids cheap- my school is on a budget…

Comment: @Edwin There are multiple types. Solenoids push or pull when energized. When de-energized a spring resets them. You have to pick the kind you need. Connect it to power with a button and it moves. Remove power with the button and it resets. Solenoids are inexpensive.

Comment: I never knew they code do that- I don’t think we ever learnt about solenoids. Thanks a lot to r13, Solar and you I have two cool ideas now. I’ve been speaking to Sir at break times and he wants me to draw a sketch up, I’ll make both this idea and r13 and see what’s cheaper really?